# FreeBusy Outlook method not working in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, outlook, outlook-2016

I am trying to get the appointment information of a contact from my company using VB.NET (not VBA) and the only method I could find for this was the FreeBusy method which VBA definition can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/recipient-freebusy-method-outlook).

I came up so far with this code :

```
Dim AppOutlook As New Outlook.Application
Dim appt As Outlook.AppointmentItem =
    CType(AppOutlook.CreateItem(
    Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem), Outlook.AppointmentItem)
Dim recip1 As Outlook.Recipient =
    appt.Recipients.Add("Jack Smith")
MsgBox(recip1.FreeBusy(#05/06/2018#, 60))
```

However, when arriving at the method FreeBusy, Visual Studio throws me an exception with the only label `Sorry, something went wrong. You may want to try again.` and no further details.

I checked if the variable receip1 was empty, but it is not and it well got the right contact with the right email address.

I really have no idea what I could have done wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to call recip1.Resolve first?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I just tried the method before the MsgBox and received a `True` answer from it, but the FreeBusy still gave me the previous error.

Comment: Are you sure it gets resolved to the expected recipient? What is the value of the recip1.Address property?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yes it is, recip1.Address() gives me the right address (I do not write it here because of privacy)

Comment: Is it SMTP or EX type address?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko SMTP I think..?

Comment: What does the address look like? Like SMTP address or something like "o=whatever/ou=something/"? Are you sure the recipient comes from your Exchange server?